# MYSQL - Join two select statements, horizontally and add NULL to unmatched rows

Tags: mysql

I have the following two select statements. The first one is:

```
SELECT SUM(film_payment.amount) AS Film_Income, MONTH(payment_date) AS Payment_Month 
FROM film_payment 
GROUP BY Payment_Month  ;
```

And the second one is:

```
SELECT SUM(series_payment.amount) AS Series_Income, MONTH(payment_date) AS Payment_Month
FROM series_payment 
GROUP BY Payment_Month ;
```

The result from the first query is:

| Film_Income | Payment_Month |
| --- | --- |
| 0.30 | 7 |
| 0.40 | 8 |
| 0.30 | 9 |
| 1.10 | 10 |
| 0.40 | 1 |

The result from the second query is:

| Series_Income | Payment_Month |
| --- | --- |
| 0.50 | 1 |
| 3.30 | 11 |
| 1.00 | 12 |

My question is, is there a way to join this two select queries to produce a table like the following?

| Payment_Month | Film_Income | Series_Income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 0.50 |
| 7 | 0.30 | NULL |
| 8 | 0.40 | NULL |
| 9 | 0.30 | NULL |
| 10 | 1.10 | NULL |
| 11 | 0.40 | 3.30 |
| 12 | NULL | 1.00 |

Meaning, joining them using the Payment_Month, and if one kind of income does not have a value during a month, then a NULL value should be added. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should add it to an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). It is easy to test it that way.

Comment: You need to simulate a full outer join.